# Errors on Xfce startup, update-notifier-crash

Tags: xfce

I get an error pop-up every time I log in, it says system service crashed or some thing like that..

I'm pretty sure this is what is happening..       any insight?

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_Xorg.0.crash) main process (3280) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_thunar.1000.crash) main process (3279) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_tracker_tracker-miner-fs.1000.crash) main process (3283) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_sbin_sfcbd.0.crash) main process (3285) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_share_software-center_software-center.1000.crash) main process (3286) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_xscreensaver.1000.crash) main process (3281) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_tumbler-1_tumblerd.1000.crash) main process (3284) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_python3.3.1000.crash) main process (3269) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_firefox_plugin-container.1000.crash) main process (3282) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_software-properties-gtk.0.crash) main process (3278) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_pavucontrol.1000.crash) main process (3264) terminated with status 1
```

Edit. I reinstalled with a new home and got the same result once I tried to get ati drivers to work, I had installed gnome in order to get to a session, that is when they started, whether it was gnome or ati i dont know.

new xsession-errors

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
Script for cjkv started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_xscreensaver.1000.crash) main process (26175) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_firefox_firefox.1000.crash) main process (26176) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_thunar.1000.crash) main process (26173) terminated with status 1
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_Xorg.0.crash) main process (26174) terminated with status 1
```

Comment: well, damn..  I was hoping someone had seen this before, I cant find anything online and I don't really want to take the time to try and wrap my head around what is going on, but I guess I will..   unless of course anyone has any input..    anyone?...   crap!..

Comment: Just posting an update, I removed update-notifier and I no longer receive the errors..    from everything thing I have read it seems it hardly works as desired any way.. and there does not seem to be any problems other than the annoyance of having the multiple pop-ups on login. so, problem solved I guess..

Comment: I've been getting the exact same symptoms in Ubuntu Studio 14.04/Xfce, and removing update-notifier appears to have resolved it for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

I removed and reinstalled `update-notifier-common` instead of `update-notifier`. That managed to solve the problem for me.